# ImageSlider in android showing error

Tags: android

The image slider works fine until i do not load images in the array. That is:

```
int imageId[]={


};
```

But as soon as i do this:

```
int imageId[]={
        R.drawable.mi

};
```

Let us that I have an activity A which has an image. Now, If i Long press on that image,Another Activity  B should start. But the android app closes abruptly.

Here is my Activity code:

```
package com.example.hotel_app_regularuser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PageTwo extends Activity {
 ViewPager vpager;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_two);
  vpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  PagerAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(PageTwo.this);
  vpager.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page_two, menu);
  return true;
 }

}


class customAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 Context context;
 int imageId[] = {
  R.drawable.mi

 };
 public customAdapter(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
 }



 public Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int item) {

  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
  View viewitem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_two, container, false);
  ImageView im = (ImageView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  im.setImageResource(imageId[item]);
  TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textView1.setText("hi");
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewitem);

  return viewitem;
 }
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return imageId.length;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }
 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
 }

}
```

Comment: show your adapter how you are using this array?

Comment: post `PagerAdapter` class

Comment: How do i find that.. I mean , i read this on internet and wrote it down.. I don't have PagerAdapter class

Comment: i find it its below `onCreateOptionsMenu()` where did you get this code.

Comment: [on this page](http://kb4dev.com/article/android-image-slider-with-swipe-gesture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
public Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int item) {
```

to :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
```

in your code and it will solve the problem.

i.e, add `@Override` and change the method name to `instantiateItem` from `InstantiateItem`

Comment: Now it gives this error:07-08 17:24:04.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11077): Process: com.example.hotel_app_regularuser, PID: 11077
07-08 17:24:04.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11077): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: now your `ImageView im = (ImageView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` returns null, check if the layout `activity_common_preferences.xml` has any `ImageView` with id `imageView1`

Comment: @ Ashish Ranjan  Sir, activity_common_preferences doesn't need to have an imageview, i guess, because i use this activity only to call another activity..so..

Comment: you're finding `R.id.imageView1` in the `activity_common_preferences.xml` so it should've an `ImagView` with that `id`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I got hold of the problem and with your suggestion, it worked flawlessly.

Comment: happy to hear that, you can accept the answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@Override` key word like i added in `InstantiateItem()` method.

```
 @Override
 public Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int item) {

  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
  View viewitem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_common_preferences, container, false);
  ImageView im = (ImageView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  im.setImageResource(imageId[item]);
  TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textView1.setText("hi");
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewitem);

  return viewitem;
 }
```

Comment: No it is not working. It says: The method instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int)must implement or override a supertype method

Comment: the program won't execute..eclipse says your project has errors pl fix them

Comment: change this line  `im.setImageResource(imageId[item]);` to `im.setImageResource(R.drawable.mi);` for testing purpose.

Comment: Nope. Now it says that void types are not allowed

Comment: when i try to do as you say, eclipse shows the red error mark, showing the message.

Comment: Comment this line and then try `//im.setImageResource(imageId[item]);`

Comment: nope.. same problem only when i comment out  `int imageId[]={
 // R.drawable.mi
      
};` The activity starts

Comment: this is some other issue then? do you have teamviwer?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that in this line:

```
View viewitem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_two,container,false);
```

i was writing:

```
View `viewitem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_commonpreferences,container,false);`
```

Also, as @ Ashish Ranjan pointed out, i changed

```
public Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int item) {
```

to

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
```

Changing these helped run my app smoothly.